# Manage Navigation Stack for SwipeView

Tags: qt, qml, swipeview, stack-navigator

Suppose I have SwipeView in my application and I will use Footer for navigating between SwipeView's Views. What approach should be followed to implement different NavigationStack for each SwipeView's Views.Is their any in-built class available for Navigation of Swipeview's Views?

Thanks

Updated:

[image]

Here is what I implemented. The issue comes when I expand screen, then click on the item in ListView and open new screen using (StackView.push()) Its not expanding relative to the width of the screen. I try many things, but no success.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `SwipeView` of [`StackViews`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-stackview.html).

You would then have to chose how does your navigation behave.

Should the previous `StackView` be cleared of all but the root page when changing to a new one?

When the users want to go back from a root page, should the app switch to the last `StackView`?
If the answer for this question is yes, you'd have to implement the swipeview history yourself.

Comment: Their could be issue with above approach.Using anchors on the items added to a StackView is not supported. Typically push, pop, and replace transitions animate the position, which is not possible when anchors are applied. Notice that this only applies to the root of the item. Using anchors for its children works as expected. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-stackview.html

Comment: It wouldn't let View expand with App's screen if i push view with StackView which is under SwipeView.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your issues.

Comment: "If the answer for this question is yes, you'd have to implement the swipeview history yourself" Why would I need to implement swipeview histroy as stackview overlaps previous view

Comment: If you want to change from one StackView to another.

Comment: @bhupinder: I have no idea what you are always talking about having stackviews overlapping previous views? In my (and probalby *GrecKo*s) imagination, you have *one* SwipeView that holds *one* StackView **per page** of the SwipeView.

Comment: @GrecKo: I am not sure whether I understand your last sentence right. To my knowledge, the `SwipeView` does not dynamically instantiate its pages. Therefore the `StackView`s remain in the same state. Am I mistaken here?

Comment: @derM What you commented above is right. I updated my question to show the problem.

Comment: @GrecKo "you have one SwipeView that holds one StackView per page of the SwipeView." This is right.